# How do I delete a row in listview by long-click and also SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I want to long click on a listview (which the data is also from the SQLite)  and then a delete pop-up menu showed up. When I click on the delete pop-up menu, the selected row in the listview will be deleted and together with the database.

view_lv_diary_info.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            PopupMenu p = new PopupMenu(ViewDiaryActivity.this, view);
            p.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_popup_menu, p.getMenu());
            p.show();

            return true;
        }           
    });
```

onDelete method:

```
public void doDelete(MenuItem mi) {

        /* db.delete(DiaryEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                ??,
                ??);
        */
        Toast.makeText(this, "Record deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I've tried this code and the toast showed up. But I don't know the SQL statement.

Thanks :)

Comment: read any tutorials about sqlite db access like [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/delete-row-in-sqlite-database.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
  listViewEdit.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
  public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> p, View v, final int po, long id) {
               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
               builder.setTitle("Delete");
               builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?");
               builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
               builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) {
                    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) p.getItemAtPosition(po);
                   // Get the state's capital from this listview_item_row in the database.
                    long ID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                    sqlcon.delete(ID); // sqlcon is one my class, InfoAPI object
                    Cursor cursor2 = sqlcon.readName();
                    dataAdapter.changeCursor(cursor2);
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                     }
                        }
                  );
                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

**InfoAPI**

```
 public void delete(long a)   // delete the selected row data 
    {
        database.delete(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, MyDatabaseHelper.ID + " =?", new String[] { a + "" });
    }
```

Comment: i just take the infoAPI, and it doesn't work. btw, thanks :)

Comment: of course it won't work, you need to use your database instead. I just show you my example

Comment: I've used my database